# Data frame with condition

Tags: r

I have the following data frame called `planets.df`:

```
     type         | planets | diameter | rotation | rings
---------------------------------------------------------
Terrestrial planet| Mercury |   0.382  |  58.64   | FALSE
Terrestrial planet|   Venus |   0.949  |-243.02   | FALSE
Terrestrial planet|   Earth |   1.000  |   1.00   | FALSE
Terrestrial planet|    Mars |   0.532  |   1.03   | FALSE
Gass giant        | Jupiter |  11.209  |   0.41   | TRUE
Gass giant        |  Saturn |   9.449  |   0.43   | TRUE
Gass giant        |  Uranus |   4.007  |  -0.72   | TRUE
Gass giant        |  Neptune|   3.883  |   0.67   | TRUE
```

I want to get all the plants that have a ring, i.e. `rings = TRUE` with the following code:

```
ring.vector <- planets.df$rings
planets.with.rings.df <- planets.df[rings.vector,]
```

Can someone tell me why this works? I didn't come up with the codes myself but want to understand why it works. The part `[rings.vector,]` means `rings=TRUE`?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot to include `ring.vector <- planets.df$rings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because in a `df[<condition,]` type of statement, the `condition` part is basically a vector of T/F. The row numbers corresponding to TRUE are kept and the ones corresponding to FALSE are omitted.

`rings.vector` is already a vector of T/F. You could instead use a `rings.vector == TRUE` condition which would give the same condition.

And in your case, it probably doesn't matter, but be careful if you have `NA`s in your `condition` vector or the column you are filtering on.

Answer (score 3):

`rings.vector` is a vector that contains indicators of `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which correspond to the column of `rings`. If you want to subset those rings with `TRUE` value, then using `[rings.vector, ]` will select **those rows that `rings==TRUE` and all columns**.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a data frame, you can reference specific rows and columns 2 different ways.

1. You can call the numbers of the columns and rows explicitly by using `df[row_numbers,column_numbers]`, or
2. You can use boolean variables (TRUE/FALSE) to indicate which rows/columns you want.  With the `rings.vector`, it will look for the row numbers that match the indices of all the TRUE values in rings.vector and pull out the corresponding rows when you use `df[rings.vector,]`.

In the above example, nothing is being checked for in the columns, but you need the comma in the brackets to indicate that the object before the comma refers to rows.  Most of the time you'll only use the boolean values for rows and specific numbers for columns out of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small reproducible example. I've added some examples using `data.table`.
Please, correct the code if it's not right.

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:100, x = rnorm(100, 100, 50))
data$flag <- ifelse(data$x > 100, TRUE, FALSE)
head(data)

# FALSE can be subseted using 0 
data[data == FALSE]
data[data == 0]
str(data$flag)

# As it's of class:
class(data$flag)

# Using Data Table
library("data.table")
DT <- data.table(data)

setkey(DT, flag)
DT[J(FALSE)]
DT[J(TRUE)]

# Aggregate (Group by)
DT[, quantile(x), by = flag]

DT[, list(mean(x), 
          sum = sum(x),
          meadian = median(x))
   , by = flag]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another angle on this is to use subset(), which is rather intuitive: it extracts only those lines from the data frame for which the condition (second argument) is true.

```
planets.with.rings.df <- subset(planets.df, rings == TRUE)
```

or just simply

```
planets.with.rings.df <- subset(planets.df, rings)
```

The "== TRUE" in the first solution is redundant since you are comparing a Boolean vector already!